# Selecting rows in SQL database based on value in column matching value in list

Tags: sql, odbc, azure-sql-database, pyodbc

I have a table with about 1.4 million rows and I want to write a sql select statement that returns all rows where the value in the first column (a unique id) is present in a list.

This list can contain between 1 and 50k id's and is generated each time a script is run and can differ each time. Based on the id number values in this list I want to only extract the rows from the database that have these id numbers in the first column.

To be more complete: I am doing all the above in a python script. This script first generates the list of ID's I need. Then I'm using pyodbc to communicate with an azure ODBC database.

My first thought was to use the 'IN' statement:

```
myquery = SELECT * FROM mydb WHERE id IN mylist
```

Obviously, this does not work since you need to specify specific values after the 'IN' statement as it is basically a replacement for 'OR' statements.

Even after a couple of hours of googling I, unfortunately, could not find an obvious and understandable way to use the 'IN' statement in combination with a variable name for mylist instead. Is this even possible in this case? Or is there another, better approach to get to the same result?

edit: Preferably I'm looking for a way without having to generate a new database table for my IDlist every time the script is run.

Comment: What DBMS are you asking about?  Most DBMS's don't have "list" as a valid datatype.

Comment: I would suggest loading the list of IDs to a `mydb.id_list` table and then following form `select * from mydb.table where id in (select id from mydb.id_list)` OR performing an `inner join` to the hypothetical `mydb.id_list` table

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: To be more clear and complete, I'm working on a python script that generates this list of ID's. Then I use python (pyodbc) to communicate with a azure database to retreive the requested data that I then have to further process. This part is about the SQL query i need to write to get the data from the database that i need

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by creating an additional extra table for the ID's as suggested.
First I make an additional table with the ID numbers, then I use this table to get the needed results from my full database and finally I remove the ID table again.

It took a little while to find the right syntax but the following allowed me to the entire process quickly:

```
# Transform my list of ID's to a list of lists
id_list = [[id] for id in ids] 
ID_TABLE = 'id_db_name'

conn = pyodbc.connect(driver='{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}',
                      server='MY_SERVER',
                      database='MY_DATABASE',
                      uid='USERNAME', pwd='PASSWORD')

cursor = conn.cursor()

# Create a new table to store the ID's
create_table = "CREATE TABLE id_db_name (Casenr varchar(12));"
cursor.execute(create_table)
cursor.commit()

# Fill the new ID table with my data
insert_to_tmp_tbl_stmt = f"INSERT INTO {ID_TABLE} VALUES (?)"
cursor.fast_executemany = True
cursor.executemany(insert_to_tmp_tbl_stmt, id_list)

# Get the rows from my full database based on the created ID table
compare = f"SELECT * FROM full_db_name WHERE Casenr in (SELECT * FROM id_db_name)"
cursor.execute(compare)
results = cursor.fetchall()

# Delete the ID table
delete_table = "DROP TABLE dbo.tempTable"
cursor.execute(delete_table)
cursor.commit()

# Close the connection
cursor.close()
conn.close()
```

Although the above code probably can be cleaned up a bit (I'm still struggeling a bit myself with the syntax, I'm quite new to SQL), it is functional and fast even for large ID tables.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem some time ago with the task of selecting a subset of a query restricted to ids (of varchar type) that the user could upload via a .csv file. The number of ids could number in the thousands, so I could not just use the IN ('id1', 'id2', ...) strategy since the IN-clause literals are restricted to 1000 literals only...

What our expert (cannot claim credit myself) came up with was:

(1) create a type by

```
create or replace TYPE ID_ARRAY as table of varchar2(12);
```

(this has to be done only once, the type will persist in your DB after this statement until you delete it)

(2) Put the literals in a statement like

```
select * from (
<insert your unrestricted sql here>
) FULL_DATA
where full_data.id in 
(
select * from table(ID_ARRAY('id1', 'id2', .... 'id5000'))
)
;
```

Would that also work in your case?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you suggest creating a new table in my database with the ID's and then using this new table to get the correctdata from my full data table. This is one of the approaches i am trying at the moment. The problem i'm running into so far however is that creating the new table is very slow as well. It can contain as many as 50.000 ids. Currently i am using a python for loop around an INSERT INTO statement to write the table entries one by one but this is taking a looong time. Is there perhaps a better way to get my IDs in this ID_ARRAY table?

Comment: Ah, the way I suggested you do not need to INSERT your ids into the new table first. Also, you do not need the CREATE TABLE and DELETE TABLE statements. You only need to add the ids to your select clause (the ('id1', 'id2', .... 'id5000') part of my proposed sql) when you compose the select string with you python code. What you *do* need to do is create the type with the statement I proposed in (1) above.

Comment: To be clear, you are saying that as long as I created the TABLE TYPE in my db and assign my ID's in Python as this TABLE TYPE it should also work? That sounds like a much more elegant solution! I'm gonna give it a try

Comment: Yes. You need to create the TYPE ID_ARRAY AS TABLE once and for good as described in (1). If you have this, you can use the syntax as described in (2), creating the list of ID literals *in that statement*. The TYPE ... AS TABLE seems to act as some sort of temporary table (I really am not an expert on this...). :D Cheers&Good Luck!

Comment: I made a table type, but I'm still struggeling with the sysntax to get everything working. If I have a python list of ID values, how do i assign them to the table type?  Something like TABLE(ID_ARRAY('list_of_IDs')).  But then a working version

Comment: unfortunately I cannot get it to work. I made the table type, (I see dbo.ID_ARRAY in sql under user defined table types), but even with a simple testcase of "select * from table(ID_ARRAY('test1', 'test2', 'test3', 'test5'))", I get a "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'table'." error in python when I try to execute. Am i missing something?

Comment: Uh, that's too bad, I am sorry, Jurjen! When I execute your test statement "select * from table(ID_ARRAY('id01', 'id02', 'id03')" I do get the result set of the three IDs..... no idea where there is a difference to your case.